# selected jquery plugin didn't work in wamp

Tags: jquery, wamp

at first i ran this code on php file and run it on localhost using WampServer. the pagination didn't work so i tried to convert it to html file ("sample.html"). the code here as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easypaginate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){

    $('ul#items').easyPaginate({
        step:5
    });

});    

    </script>

    <style>
        #page li {
          display: inline;
          position: relative;
          width: 11em
          margin:10px; 
          padding:10px;
        }
        #page li li{ display: block; height: 1.5em;}

    </style>


<div id = "page">       
<ul id="items">
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>Page 3</li>
    <li>Page 4</li>
    <li>Page 5</li>
    <li>Page 6</li>
    <li>Page 7</li>
    <li>Page 8</li>
    <li>Page 9</li>
    <li>Page 10</li>
    <li>Page 11</li>
    <li>Page 12</li>
    <li>Page 13</li>
    <li>Page 14</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

i transferred this code on sample.html but the case is. the jquery is not working when i ran it on localhost. but when i Open With - > Google Chrome the sample.html file the jquery work. I think the problem is not in the code. the problem occured when i ran the file via localhost even if it is a .html or .php file. help me please T_T

---

when i ran the code through localhost this output is produced

Page 1 Page 2 Page 3 Page 4 Page 5 Page 6 Page 7 Page 8 Page 9 Page 10 Page 11 Page 12 Page 13 Page 14

but when i ran it directly on a browser Open With -> *Browser*
this is the output

```
Page 1    Page 2    Page 3    Page 4    Page 5

1    2    3    Next
```

Comment: There's more to question here, can you please give any error which you get while using this code on wamp server? Try looking in google chrome console for that..

Comment: looks like your relative paths are not correct, please make sure your are files are reaching client, jquery core, plugin etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the source for any errors generated by PHP. it seems you are doing some invalid things in your server side.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zu3Ae/

Comment: i didn't touched any configuration in the wamp server. T_T. jqueries are only working when I do Open With -> Browser. T_T

Comment: doesn't mean any configuration on the wamp. did you put the same code inside the wamp? if yes use your js as `/js/easypaginate.js` and check the `js` directory is there in the root of the site.

Comment: i tried it. and BOOM the error appeared . you don't have permission to access /pagination/easypaginate.js on this server. i think it's a configuration problem what i must do?

Comment: the jquery 1-4.4 also is forbidden is there any global url for that that i can access ?? in any case , how can i solve this problem? is this a problem in my wamp?

Comment: it already works but em not that satisfied why my wamp server gone crazy handling this files with restrictions "403 Forbidden Error" i didn't encountered this last time :(( BTW Thank You!

Comment: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js` use google CDN for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Remember that JavaScript is run client side, so where the files are served from makes no difference. Which leads me to believe the relevant files are *not* being served.

Your best bet, imho, is to add a `<base>` href tag to your html. e.g.

```
<base href="//localhost/SouthSapphire2/" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easypaginate.js"></script>
```

In that example, the presumption is that you have a directory `js` that has your JavaScrpt files, and that that js directory is sitting inside your directory `SouthSapphire2`.

Comment: @JohnMicahFernandezMiguel as vishwanath noted, I bet it's a relative path issue. What is the URL when you view the html file served by WAMP?

Comment: @JohnMicahFernandezMiguel is `jquery-1.3.1.min.js` located inside a js folder inside `SouthSapphire2` or a directory higher?

Comment: i ran the file with this file:///C:/wamp/www/SouthSapphire2/sample.html it worked....... i ran the file with this http://localhost/SouthSapphire2/sample.html it DID NOT WORKED T_T